# USB not showing in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-17.10

when i type `lsusb` than it shows these devices

[image]
In here, `A-DATA Technologo Co., LTd.` is my `pendrive` and

and `Samsung Electronics co., Ltd Galaxy` is my `phone`.

both are not showing in files  -

OS: `ubuntu 17.10`

PC:  `dell inspiron 3542`.

what is the solution ??

Comment: over the past year or so I too have noticed lack of proper USB connectivity from ubuntu to android for anything 16.04 or above ... however the SO sibling site is a better place for such questions  https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

First try to see your volumes by writing

fdisk -l

This will show your volumes. When you see /dev/sdb (and its partition sdb1), run the following commands to format your drive

umount /dev/sdb1
mkfs.vfat -n 'pendrive-name' -I /dev/sdb1

After that you may eject the drive with

sudo eject /dev/sdb

Now again insert the drive and the pendrive will be visible.